# How to store type in a Java Tuple implementation

Tags: java, types, tuples

I am looking to create a data structure to store an `Object` and its actual type in structured format. I am dealing with data where everything is being passed around as `Objects` and coming in as such.

I am hoping to either adapt [Apache Commons Pair](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/package-summary.html) or build a data structure class.

The data comes into the application as a `Map<String, Object>`. This `Map` can be nested quite deeply, so I am working on a function that walks through the `Map` given a path string. This string contains contains the key for each layer in the nested map, seperated by `.`. For example, a path string could look like `"path.to.some.field"`.

Currently, there is a lot of the following sort of idiom being used in the codebase:

```
Map<String, Object> data;
if (data.containsKey("someKey")) {
  Object obj = data.remove("someKey")
  if (obj instanceof Map< ? , ? >) {
    Map<String, Object> objMap = (Map<String, Object>) obj;
    // repeat...
  }
}
```

While this works, it is a lot of checking and type casting as you move though the outer map `data`. As I said, I am working on a function that can abstract this out into a function that walks the `Map`. I want to be able to return data that is readily usable. Something like:

```
public DataPair findDataEntry(Map<String, Object> currentMap, String path)
{
   // recursive function that walks map. 
   // It also checks type as well as if the path is valid as it goes along
   // returns a structure containing the object and its 'type'

   return new DataPart(type, entry)
}
```

Example usage:

```
DataPair p = findDataEntry(data, path);
p.left dataentry = new p.left;
dataentry = p.right;
```

This may not be possible in Java, as it would require dynamic declaration of `dataentry` use the variable type information stored in `p.left`. `p.left` could be any `type`, from `int` to `String` to `SomeClass`.

See [Object Creation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html). If Java does not support using variable types in Object declaration, then the whole goal of this question is moot.

My question is: How do I store the type information (like `List<String>`) in the data structure?

Comment: Have you considered using something like Jackson to either bind the map to pojos or traverse the path for you? What I'm getting at is rethinking the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Why? An object contains its own type. You don't need a pair.

Comment: To elaborate on EJP's comment, objects have a `getClass()` method, and you can always use `instanceof`

Comment: @DavidEhrmann I am trying to abstract away a bunch of `instanceof` checks in the main application functions. There are only a limited number of possibilities for the type of a given object in this data. The idea was to return a pair of type and object. There may be a different or better way of doing this as well...

Comment: @Andrew so, instead of `instanceof` you want to do `if pair.right == ???`, right?

Comment: I don't see why you need anything more complex than your existing code in a `while` loop, to chase the cases where `get()` returns a `Map`.

Comment: Remember that Java reflection is not true and complete reflection.  Generically polymorphic collections are difficult in Java. Whenever you want to use reflection in the manner you seem to be proposing you _will_ end up writing casts all over the place.  However, the code to walk a path should be a single recursive method... is that not the case in your code?  Show us some examples of what you want your clients to be able to write (in the question, not in comments)

Comment: @EJP. I was aiming to for a structure that I could then use to dynamically construct an object with its return type. Some like `dataPair = findDataEntry(data, path)` and then `dataPair.left dataEntry = new dataPair.left` and then `dataEntry = dataPair.right`

Comment: And you still haven't told us why. Not that any of that compiles.

Comment: @JimGarrison You are right and what I may be aiming for may be something one cannot do in Java. I do have a single recursive method already coded that works. It currently returns just `Object`.

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: @D.B. Perhaps you are right. This may be more of a question of storing and dynamically typing and `Object` in java.

Comment: Until you show us WHY you want to do this and HOW the users of this would actually use it, it is too abstract, hypothetical, and firmly in the realm of XY Problem.

Comment: @JimGarrison The use case would to use this information to directly and dynamically institute an object. To be able to do `type data = new type`, where `type` is within the return value of a function.

Comment: Please write an actual sample of valid, concrete Java client code, not pseudocode, showing how your system would be used, and add that to your question.

Comment: @JimGarrison I have updated the question. I am really starting to think, that in addition to this question being flawed, I may be trying to do something that the Java language does not support.

Comment: How is `p.left dataentry = new p.left;` valid Java?  That is not possible in a compiled, strongly typed language like Java.

Comment: @Andrew lets imagine that it is possible, how the rest of the code with `dataentry` could look like? I mean at compile time you don't know type, so you cannot call any method or property, so you cannot use variable `dataentry `

Comment: @JimGarrison You are right. This is not something that the Java Language Supports. Some other languages could do this, like loosely typed runtime languages.

Comment: @Andrew what languages support this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a pair. An object already contains its own type. It seems to me that all you need is this:

```
public Object findDataEntry(Map<String, Object> map, String path)
{
    Object obj;
    while ((obj = map.remove(path)) != null) {
        if (obj instanceof Map) {
            map = (Map<String, Object>) obj;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```